# ReHosting Workflow Designer - Change orientation of toolbox

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, workflow-foundation-4

I am rehosting the Workflow designer, but the xaml for the toolbox shows the activities aligned vertically with an indentation. I need to host my custom activies and a few basic activities horizontally like they are in a toolbar. I tried with stackpanel as the container but in vain. The following is the code snippet.

```
 <Border Grid.Column="0">
            <sapt:ToolboxControl>
                <sapt:ToolboxCategory CategoryName="" >
                    <sapt:ToolboxItemWrapper AssemblyName="{StaticResource AssemblyName}" >
                        <sapt:ToolboxItemWrapper.ToolName>
                            System.Activities.Statements.Sequence
                        </sapt:ToolboxItemWrapper.ToolName>
                       </sapt:ToolboxItemWrapper>
                    <sapt:ToolboxItementer code hereWrapper  AssemblyName="{StaticResource AssemblyName}">
                        <sapt:ToolboxItemWrapper.ToolName>
                            System.Activities.Statements.WriteLine
                        </sapt:ToolboxItemWrapper.ToolName>
             </sapt:ToolboxItemWrapper>
                </sapt:ToolboxCategory>
            </sapt:ToolboxControl>
        </Border>
```